# Android Studio Cryptogrophy: Vigenère Cypher

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, computer-science

I have a problem with Vigenère I know that I have to shift the text so A is supposed to be shifted by 0 but in my project A shifts by 1 and Z is 0 instead of 26. I keep on getting numbers instead of the encrypted/decrypted letters.

public void Vigenre() {

```
    final EditText input3 = new EditText(this);
    final String word = input3.getText().toString();


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Input in word:");
    input3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    builder.setView(input3);
    builder
            .setMessage("What word will you use?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //If Radio button Decrypt is selected run this code bellow:
                    if (Decrypt.isChecked()) {
                        String text = Input.getText().toString();
                        String key = input3.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                                , key + "," + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String res = "";
                        text = text.toUpperCase();
                        key = key.toUpperCase();
                        //Output.setText("TEST");
                        for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                            char c = text.charAt(i);
                            if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
                                continue;
                            res += (char) ((c - key.charAt(j) + 26 - 'A') % 26 + 'A');
                            j = ++j % key.length();
                            //Output.setText("Test");
                        }
                        Output.setText(res);
                        return;
                        // Output.setText("TEST");
                    }
                    //If Radio button Encrypt is selected run this code bel/low:
                    else if (Encrypt.isChecked()) {
                        String text = Input.getText().toString();
                        String key = input3.getText().toString();
                        String res = "";
                        text = text.toUpperCase();
                        key = key.toUpperCase();
                       // Output.setText("TEST");
                        for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                            char c = text.charAt(i);
                            if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
                                continue;
                            res += (char) ((c + key.charAt(j) - 2 - 'A' + 1) % 26 + 'A');
                            j = ++j % key.length();
                        }
                    //Output.setText("TEST");
                    Output.setText(res);
                    return;

                }
            }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Pleas help me!! This is HW for my school class. Thanks!

Comment: Double check this expression: `(c - key.charAt(j) + 26 - 'A') % 26 + 'A'` with a few examples. Does it really do what you want?

Comment: No, it prints out a number like when I put in ab with a shift of a I get 5 instead of bc

Comment: This is HW so I will not give you the full answer. Check all sub-expressions, do they have the value you think they should have?

Comment: I feel like I shoulden't be adding 'A' because it might be making the number go to number section(I forgot what it was called) instead of a letter..

Comment: after the `% 26` you have a number in the range 0..25 so adding 'A' seems ok as it will result in a character in the range 'A'..'Z'.

Comment: To be honest, I'm kind of lost..... I'm starting to believe Android studio is plotting against me.

Comment: Just think it through, it is really not difficult. Which variables hold character values (range 'A'..'Z')? You want to make your calculations with numbers in the range 0..25. So first convert all characters to low range numbers, calculate, convert back to a character. Once you have written down the full formula you will see how it can be simplified.